# I cannot Have strings in my Class. Why?

Tags: c++

I am having issues with my game. I haven't made much of a game so far, but I am trying to call a string using a external function from my bin class. When I compile, It says I can't have non-static variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Bin {
    string gameStart = "How would you like to start?\n";
};

Bin bin1;

int main () {
    cout << bin1.gameStart;
}
```

Just for reference, I have tried looking for solutions, but to no prevail.

Update: Hi again. I have read some of the feedback from my question. I see that Raw N and Angew have made some valid points. I would like to ask if these two nice people: Where does the  header go. How can i get that version of the compiler?

Thanks!

Update: I managed to find out how to compile my code in c++14. There is a console command that can be used for this. I updated my open.bat file, which i use to compile my notepad code. Everything is working fine now. Thanks all!

Comment: Include the `<string>` header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: In addition to what Raw N said, you need to compile as C++11 or newer to have support for in-class initialisers for non-static data members.

Comment: When asking about a compile problem, please copy and paste the *exact* error message into the question.

Comment: You need to provide an accurate description of the problem. "It says I can't have non-static variables" is not an accurate decription of the problem but rather a product of your own imagination.

Comment: You did at least produce complete code, but it wasn't really "minimal" - I have removed some irrelevant lines.

Answer (score 4):

The default for a class' members is `private`, so without specifying differently, your data will not be accessible from outside the class.
Add `public:` inside the class, before the declarations.

Comment: On your point 2:  He *has* an object of class `Bin` - called `bin1`.

Comment: I think this is much more likely to be that he isn't using a C++11 compiler.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, Aganju, I recognise that there should have been a public: snippet in there. I actually had that in my code, but I deleted it while trying numerous methods to fix my problem. Thanks anyway.